# $f: R\rightarrow [0,\infty] $ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: R\rightarrow [0,\infty] $ is measurable. Then, $\int_{R} f= c$ where $0< c< \infty $

\begin{equation}
\lim \int n \,  \log \left(1+ \left(\frac{f}{n}\right)^{\alpha} \right) =
 \begin{cases}
    \infty & \text{if} & 0< \alpha < 1 \\
    c & \text{if} & \alpha =1 \\
    0 & \text{if} & 1 < \alpha < \infty \\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation} 
We need to check that if $\alpha \geq 1$, the integrands are dominated by $\alpha f$ and if $\alpha < 1$, apply Fatou's lemma.
 But, I don't solve this question. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let us show that $\log (1+t^{\alpha}) \leq \alpha t$ for $t \geq 0$ and $\alpha \geq 1$. For this note that the derivative of $\alpha t -\log (1+t^{\alpha})$ is $\alpha -\frac {\alpha t^{\alpha -1}} {1+t^{\alpha}}$. This is non-negative because $1+t^{\alpha} > t^{\alpha-1}$ for all $t \geq 0$. Since $\alpha t -\log (1+t^{\alpha})$ vanishes when $t=0$ we see that is is non-negative for all $t \geq 0$. This proves our claim. We have proved that the integrand in the given integral is dominated by the integrable function $\alpha f$ when $\alpha \geq 1$. Apply DCT to finish the proof when $\alpha \geq 1$.

Now let $\alpha <1$. The $nlog(1+(\frac f n)^{\alpha})\to \infty$ whenever $f >0$. [This is because $log (1+x) \sim x$ as $x \to 0$]. By Fatou's Lemma we get $\lim \inf \int nlog(1+(\frac f n)^{\alpha}) \geq \infty$ since $f>0$ with positive measure and $\int_{f>0} \infty =\infty$. [$f>0$ with positive measure  because $\int f =c >0$].

Comment: Thanks Dear Kavi Rama Murthy.